# I want to develop an Android chat app using PHP. How can I do it? without using Google Firebase Cloud Messeging and AWS

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an **Android chat app** using PHP. How can I do it? **without using Google Firebase Cloud Messeging and Amazon Web Service**.

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Comment: PHP is not a good option for ChatApp. you need realtime connections. Learn more about sockets.
I would use [Vert.x](https://vertx.io) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it host your own Messaging server using software's like RabbitMQ and then using MQTT protocol you can take benefits of pub-sub architecture for real-time messaging app.

https://dev.to/dianamaltseva8/rabbitmq-for-building-mobile-chats--messengers-sharing-experience-358